# How to setup a DocuSign handler on Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, docusignapi

I actually use YouSign to sign registration PDFs when a user creates an account on the website of the company I work for.

We have loads of document to sign, multiple times, and want to switch to DocuSign because it allows more documents in each API calls.

I'm on Symfony 2.8 (Going for Symfony 3 soon), and I want to setup DocuSign before migrating.

Let's say I already have all the fields value variables assigned (`$name`, `$wage`, `lastName`...), and a PDF document created with all these values.
I want to sign this document with DocuSign, how can I do ?
I requested the DocuSign/eSign package but have no idea of how to use it.

I already checked all the example codes on GitHub and did not find any using a Symfony template.

Do you know how to integrate the classes and methods needed to send a PDF to DocuSign, sign it, and then get it back using the PHP wrapper in Symfony ?

Comment: I have been using docuSign with php native and cakePHP, you could use the docusign-php-client it's very easy to use. Also, if you have predefined document you could use document-library it's more simple

Comment: I know there is a PHP Wrapper but I'm trying to figure out a way to use it, and it's hard since there is no documentation, but just code examples with one or two private functions with no background...
I import the eSign package with `use DocuSign\eSign;`, but after this, I don't know how to create envelopes or anything, I guess I'll just go in the vendor and check the methods

Comment: I used it with templates, you can follow my code example ( see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some PHP code you can use as a starting point.
https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG001EmbeddedSigning.php

Here is the code:

```
# 1. Create the envelope request object
        $envelope_definition = $this->make_envelope($envelope_args);
        # 2. call Envelopes::create API method
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        $config->setHost($args['base_path']);
        $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
        $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
        $envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);
        $results = $envelope_api->createEnvelope($args['account_id'], $envelope_definition);
        $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();
        # 3. Create the Recipient View request object
        $authentication_method = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
        # the signer? See the `authenticationMethod' definition
        # https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient
        $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
            'authentication_method' => $authentication_method,
            'client_user_id' => $envelope_args['signer_client_id'],
            'recipient_id' => '1',
            'return_url' => $envelope_args['ds_return_url'],
            'user_name' => $envelope_args['signer_name'], 'email' => $envelope_args['signer_email']
        ]);
        # 4. Obtain the recipient_view_url for the signing ceremony
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        $results = $envelope_api->createRecipientView($args['account_id'], $envelope_id,
            $recipient_view_request);
```

we have a PHP library that would assist you here - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client

Comment: What is `$this` in this case ? Am I supposed to implement something in my Symfony Controller ?

Comment: $this is whatever class you're working in. You are supposed to implement this code, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function docusignSignature( $docusignTemplate, $userInput, $emailSettings  )
{

    // create configuration object and configure custom auth header
    $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost(ESIGN_HOST);
    $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . ESIGN_USER . "\",\"Password\":\"" . ESIGN_PASS . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . ESIGN_KEY . "\"}");

    //enable SSL_verification since we're on prod
    $config->setSSLVerification(true);

    // instantiate a new docusign api client
    $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    $accountId = null;

    $user_id    = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
    $user_name  = $_SESSION['user']['name']." ({$_SESSION['user']['name']})";

    if(empty($user_id) || empty($user_email)) {
        echo json_encode(array( 'error'=>"Not logged in, please reload the page."
            ));
        exit;
    }

    try 
    {
        //*** STEP 1 - Login API: get first Account ID and baseURL
        $authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
        $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
        $loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);

        if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
        {
            $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
            $host = $loginAccount->getBaseUrl();
            $host = explode("/v2",$host);
            $host = $host[0];

            // UPDATE configuration object
            $config->setHost($host);

            // instantiate a NEW docusign api client (that has the correct baseUrl/host)
            $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);

            $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();

            if(!empty($accountId))
            {
                //*** STEP 2 - Signature Request from a Template
                // create envelope call is available in the EnvelopesApi
                $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

                //Prepare an emailNotification
                $emailNotification=new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEmailNotification();

                //set email content
                $emailNotification->setEmailBody($emailSettings['emailBody'])
                    ->setEmailSubject($emailSettings['emailSubject'])
                    ->setSupportedLanguage("en");


                $textTabs=array();//prepare tabs (TextTab[])
                $radioGroups=array();//prepare radioGroups
                foreach ($userInput as $key => $value) {
                    if(is_null($value))continue;

                    if (is_array($value) && isset($value['type']) && $value['type']=='radio') {
                        $radio=new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Radio(
                                    array(
                                        'tab_id'    =>$value['value'],
                                        'value'     =>$value['value'],
                                        'selected'  =>true
                                    ));
                        $radioGroups[]=new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RadioGroup(array(
                                        'group_name'    =>$key,
                                        'radios'        =>array($radio)
                                    ));
                        continue;
                    }

                    if(is_bool($value) || $value=='Yes') {
                        //just skip it (we changed checkboxes by radio)
                        continue;
                    }

                    $textTabs[]=new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text(
                                    array(
                                        'tab_label' =>$key,//tab_label is the input name, see the template in the Account
                                        'value'     =>$value//value to be set to the input
                                    ));
                }

                $tabs=new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['text_tabs'=>$textTabs]);

                //radio buttons
                if(!empty($radioGroups)){
                    $tabs->setRadioGroupTabs($radioGroups);
                }

                $templateRole = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
                $templateRole->setEmail($user_email);
                $templateRole->setName($user_name);
                $templateRole->setTabs($tabs);
                $templateRole->setEmailNotification($emailNotification);
                $templateRole->setRoleName("role1");//check defined roles in your settings

                $templateRoles=array($templateRole);

                //a logic to Add a CC to all forms
                $ccEmailNotif=new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEmailNotification();
                //set email content
                $ccEmailNotif->setEmailBody( CC_EMAIL_BODY )
                    ->setEmailSubject( CC_EMAIL_SUBJECT )
                    ->setSupportedLanguage("en");

                $supportRole = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
                $supportRole->setEmail( CC_EMAIL_DEFAULT )
                    ->setName('Support')
                    ->setEmailNotification($ccEmailNotif)
                    ->setRoleName("support");
                $templateRoles[]=$supportRole;

                // instantiate a new envelope object and configure settings
                $envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();

                $envelop_definition->setTemplateId($docusignTemplate);
                $envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles($templateRoles);

                // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
                $envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");

                // create and send the envelope (signature request)
                $envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition);
                if(!empty($envelop_summary))
                {
                    //grap some infos from the evelope_summary
                    $envelopeID     =$envelop_summary->getEnvelopeId();
                    $envelopeStatus =$envelop_summary->getStatus();
                    $envelopeDate   =$envelop_summary->getStatusDateTime();
                    $filePath       =__FILE__;

                    echo json_encode(
                        array( 'success'=>'An electronic signature is sent.')
                    );
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DocuSign\eSign\ApiException $ex)
    {
        // do something with the exception
    }
}
```